# how to edit or remove the dashboard footer message

Tags: customization, dashboard

I insert the following simple code in the functions.php to edit the message in the footer dashboard  "Thank you for creating with WordPress." 
but nothing changes.
I have Version 4.9.8
Do you think this code is not effected in version 4 ?

```
// Admin footer modification

function remove_footer_admin () {
    echo '<span id="footer-thankyou">Developed by <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a></span>';
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'remove_footer_admin');
```

Comment: Note that if this was a filter, you would be passed the value as an argument and have to return the new value. You can't just `echo` out the result in a filter, that's not how filters work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [White Label CMS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/) plugin. Using this plugin you can change footer message and as well as you can update almost all the default settings.

1. Install & activate [White Label CMS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/white-label-cms/) plugin
2. Go to Admin Panel >> Settings >> White Label CMS. See this https://prnt.sc/l8xah5
3. Click on Branding.
4. Under the Footer Section, add your custom footer message and Save the changes.